# Optional wizard page best practice (Skip VS Next button text)

Tags: buttons, wizard

After a user buys a giftcard, he gets to the following giftcard redeem webpage:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhJ9Kp.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

1. The user chooses a country.
2. When clicking on Next, he/she gets a screen where he can accept / decline some special offers. If the user is not interested, he can click on the 'Skip' button to go to the summary screen.
3. If the user chooses to accept the offer, he should click on the 'Accept Offer' button and then he'll get a confirmation dialog that the offer was recorded.
4. On the offer confirmation modal, once the user clicks on the continue button he is transfered to the summary screen.
5. If an offer was accepted and a user clicks on back on the summary screen, he will see the offers screen in 'Selected' mode. This is meant to show the user that the offer was accepted and that he can cancel it. **The important thing to notice here is that the 'Skip' button text was changed to 'Next'.**

**My question is:**

If the user cancels the offer, should the 'Next' button text be changed back to 'Skip' or does it make more sense to leave it as 'Next'?

Answer (score 1):

The simple fact is that users don't look. If the button said next on all the previous screens they will never notice that the text has changed.

I did a screenshot of a window for a "What's wrong with this?" example with the next and back button reversed, and it is always the last thing everyone notices.

A better solution might be to have a checkbox on your subscription offer, which you can check / uncheck to add / remove, and leave the next button as "Next".

Answer (score 0):

Most users click on the buttons habitually. They really don't read the texts. every button positioned in the right side (in English context) means `Next`.

Changing the label of a button is a type of action which makes an experience without confirmation and most users are not aware about it. So you simply miss the target.

Why not having both `Next` and `Skip` buttons with different visual appearance? This minimize the cognitive load.

[image]

Comment: Ok lets say that skip would be without the fill color (only border) while back and next have solid fills. Still, the question is which would make more sense to use in the case described...

Comment: When you are showing both buttons, why are you going to change the label? see the update please.

Answer (score 0):

Try to think off and design journeys like this to be always going forward.

(I'd lose the "congratualtions" screen and put this information on the summary page. On the sumarry page I'd put a "remove free subscription" link. This then takes the user to a summary page with the subscription removed and no "back" link.)

Comment: The congradulations screen is important because an offer is not always a subscription.. it can be something that actualy changes the giftcard amount i.e get 5$ extra for your giftcard if you change the brand (store) of your gift card from X to Y. In this case the user has to get an 'udpate' about the change in amount... something like "Congradulations, your gift card is now worth 35$". The user has to get a visual 'reward' for accepting the offer. Any thoughts?

Comment: With knowing more of the specifics I still don't see why this can't happen on the summary page. It's generally true (and I've seen this on many sites) that every step you remove will reduce drop out. There doesn't seem to be a lot of information on either screen so users can probably understand both concepts. (Also this is good news, ending a process on a hight is always nice)